# How can I translate this linq query to a breeze query

Tags: breeze

I am in the process of learning Durandal and Breeze. And have choosing to create a SPA version of nerddinner.

The first query I need to execute is this:

```
 public IEnumerable<JsonDinner> GetMostPopularDinners(int limit = 10)
    {
       var mostPopularDinners = from dinner in _db.Context.Dinners.Include("RSVPs")
                                where dinner.EventDate >= DateTime.Now
                                orderby dinner.RSVPs.Count descending
                                select dinner;

        if (limit > 50 || limit <= 0)
            limit = 10;

        return mostPopularDinners.Take(limit).AsEnumerable().Select(JsonDinnerFromDinner);
    }
```

I have started to write it with breeze but I am having trouble with this line " orderby dinner.RSVPs.Count descending" this is what I have so far.

```
var getMostPopularDinners = function() {
        var query = EntityQuery
            .from('dinners')
            .where('eventDate', '>=', new Date(Date.now()))
            .orderByDesc('RSVPs')
            .expand('RSVPs');
```

Comment: Martin, what trouble are you having? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Breeze doesn't yet support ordering or filtering on an aggregate value ('count' in this case).

What you can do is turn this into a named query. (which is not well documented...) Basically this involves using the *EntityQuery.withParameters* method to pass additional parameters to any service method. So you can construct a query like the following that both passes parameters and still uses Breeze's IQueryable support.

```
EntityQuery.from("GetMostPopularDinners")
             .withParameters({ EventDate: new Date(Date(now()) })
             .take(10);
```

where your controller method would look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Dinner> GetMostPopularDinners(DateTime eventDate) {
      return _db.Context.Dinners.
         .Where(dinner => dinner.EventDate >= eventDate)
         .OrderByDescending(dinner => dinner.RSVPs.Count);
}
```

and ... you should not need to do an JsonDinnerFromDinner" call; Breeze handles this automatically.